# Vite build package and static site simultaneously

Tags: vite

I'm use Vite to preview/test my package locally (with `vite`) and then build the package with `vite build`. My project folder structure looks something like this:

```
├── dist
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── main.d.ts
│   └── mypackage.js
├── lib
│   ├── main.ts       // Package exports 
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── ...           // Other files/folders
├── src
│   └── main.ts
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

I would like to set things up such that whenever I build the package, I also build a static site based on `index.html` and `src/main.ts`, and deploy it as Github pages whenever I push to main.

Is there a simple way to do this?